# Nginx + SSL server not responding

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm migrating some sites from Apache to Nginx and trying to get one configured to answer SSL requests. At the moment I'm getting a **server not responding** error. If I switch to port 80 I get an nginx error (not worried about the error itself since nginx is at least serving it up).

For this site, I want it to *only* answer ssl requests. Here's what the server block looks like:

```
server {
  listen      443;
  server_name dev.project.mydomain.net;
  root        /opt/dev/project-root;
  index       index.php;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/vh.dev-project.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/vh.dev-project.error.log;

  location /aliasing/ {
    alias /opt/dev/project-root/aliased;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

My http block:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Your server-block itself looks okay. Can you post the rest of your configuration? (E.g. nginx.conf)

Comment: And btw, since nginx 0.7.14 the preferred way of enabling SSL is by using the `ssl` parameter in the `listen` directive like this: `listen 443 default_server ssl;`

Comment: Thanks for the insight. What is the `default_server` component? This is just one virtual host, so I want to be sure it's not doing anything outside of that scope.

Comment: @pkhamre - Added my http block above. Any other config tips you may have are always welcome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have opened up port TCP443 on your firewall if you have one enabled, I hope? (It's an obvious one, but I've missed this before myself.)

Comment: You're close. The port was open, but not forwarding properly from the external router. Ugh.

Comment: man, u saved my life!